# Query regarding Android facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I want to make a test app which uses android facebook sdk.
I have followed all the steps mentioned at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

I am using following snippet given at this link

```
public class AndroidFacebookActivity extends Activity {     
    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("282009485165563");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }
```

However when i run this app on emulator, I get following error
**The Appliaction has stopped unexpectedly**.
from Logcat i see following

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook
```

I have built the facebook application and installed it successfully before running my app.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you downloaded the Facebook for Android SDK?

Comment: yes, But I not able to import it or add it is as library in properties->android->add library.
So i added it as link source

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it.
Right click on facebook project->Android->check IsLibrary option.
now go to your app, and when you go to add library, it would list facebook library.
just select it and you are good to go...